# Firefox Bookmarklet in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I wrote a little bookmarklet that works great in firefox, trying to use it in Chrome and not having any luck.  Just tried out a stub bookmarklet javascript:alert('wtf'); which works fine in Firefox but not at all in Chrome. Trying to pick apart a couple of my pre-installed Chrome Bookmarklets and can't figure out why they run and mine don't. Having a lot of trouble finding  documentation on this, thought I'd ask:

The javascript that I use is pretty much identical between Firefox and Chrome, the javascript: command for the bookmarklet is identical between my firefox bookmarklets and pre-installed chrome bookmarklets, so is there something else going on here?

Here's the actual bookmarklet (not just the stub)
    javascript:function(){myscript=document.createElement('SCRIPT');myscript.type='text/javascript';myscript.src='http://applegator.net/script.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(myscript);}

Some strange formatting things happened to it when it landed in chrome, still trying to sort it out, but think its basically right.

Am pretty new to Chrome so maybe this is something to do with them, just can't figure it out.
Thanks,

Comment: Which version are you using? Did you copy-paste the code in the adressbar? If yes, "not working" the expected effect.

Comment: When I typed `javascript:alert('wtf')` into the address bar of chrome, it worked fine. Be aware that Chrome will not let you paste "javascript:" into the URL bar, you must type it. I have created several Chrome bookmarklets and they work fine. What do you mean by "pre-installed Chrome Bookmarklets"??? As far as I know, chrome does not come with any pre-installed bookmarklets, and so I wonder if you are not confused about something. Or maybe I am wrong, and you can enlighten me.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was being hasty and pissed. not pre-installed, 'written by somebody else and previously installed by me. I got my stub working, but the actual bookmarklet (which is really just a loader for a longer file) still doesn't. Guess I should probably paste that code in here.

Comment: Chrome apparently inserted an extra 'javascript:function()' and also converted all my %20's back into spaces (which I think are not good in bookmarlets, but maybe I'm wrong). Still can't get it to run, I'm screwing around with it but if there's something obvious, I would love to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, managed to work it out, the real problem seems to have been the strange formatting and the cutting and pasting. Thanks for the help...I guess I don't really understand why the formatting did that, or whats so bad about cut and paste, but this is something I can work with. Could I get you to move your comment to an answer so I can accept it? Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I just added your bookmarklet successfully in Chrome.  However, I discovered that bookmarklets will not run on certain important pages like the New Tab page or anything else that starts with `chrome://`.

Perhaaps your choice of test page is your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a space after the javascript: alert('like so');

if you want to do anything more complex, use a closure:

javascript: a=function(){alert('poop');alert('morepoop');}();

the (); is a shortcut for self-invocation of the closure